# Why are adverbs written in hiragana sometimes?

Tags: grammar, usage

The more I read Japanese and use this site. I notice sentences that have adverbs sometimes are written in hiragana.

Example found on this site ([source](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3140/1478)):

> アイスが溶けているよ。はやく食べなさい。
>   Your ice cream is melting. Hurry up and eat it.

Why was 早くnot used in this sentence?

What's the logic behind this and when should you use it?

Comment: For lexicalized adverbs like おそらく/すべて/ついに, please see [Why words such as しばらく are almost always written in kana while words such as 石鹸 are usually in kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21637/5010)

Comment: `adverbs` -- Is はやく(はやい) an adverb or i-adjective?

Answer (score 8):

Not only adverb, first, difficult kanji is often written in hiragana.

Second, when they are not sure which kanji should be used properly, it is often written in hiragana. For example, 早い or 速い, 図る or 計る or 測る or 量る or 謀る.

Third, hiragana gives more affinity and softness than kanji for us. Related: [Why is the place's official name written as "なら工藝館" (rather than "奈良工藝館")?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/35785/why-is-the-places-official-name-written-as-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89%e5%b7%a5%e8%97%9d%e9%a4%a8-rather-than-%e5%a5%88%e8%89%af%e5%b7%a5%e8%97%9d%e9%a4%a8)